# vim could not load library python26.dll but i'm using python 2.7?

Tags: python, vim, omnicomplete

Using vim and when I try use omnicomplete for python I get an error

```
Required vim compiled with +python.
```

When I try

```
:python print 'hello'
```

I get

```
E370: Could not load library python26.dll
```

Strangely I'm using python 2.7 anyway so how can I change what python vim should use or will I have to install python 2.6 to use this feature?

Comment: which version of vim/gvim are you using?

Comment: i installed the cream pack. so it's vim 7.3, gvim and cream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to have the same version of python installed that vim was compiled against.  That means you either need to install 2.6 or recompile vim against 2.7 (or find an existing binary that already is).